# What is wrong with the way I am passing arguments to get_tags()?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This bit of code has been giving me a problem. Here's the snippet in question:

```
... strip_tags($product->get_tags(array('order', 'DESC'))) ...
```

Which should produce a reverse alphabetical list of tags from the product, however, something entirely different comes up on the front-end. While get_tags() does work without arguments, as soon as I add any argument it produces this error.

[image: WTF get_tags]

Following a commenter's suggestion of using this:

```
strip_tags($product->get_tags(array('order' => 'DESC')))
```

Produces this:

[image: WTF get_tags() freaking out]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about `WC_Product` class and `get_tags()` method then function [definition](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1178-1188) is:

```
function get_tags( $sep = ', ', $before = '', $after = '' )
```

It returns list of term links ( in fact, just returns [get_the_term_list()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) list ).

Comment: That is what I was missing -- thank you! This isn't a Wordpress function by the same name...